# How can I set an setOnClickPendingIntent for my entire widget layout?

Tags: java, android, android-widget, android-pendingintent

I'd like to set an `setOnClickPendingIntent` for my entire widget layout but I haven't found a a way to do this. I guess it's something very trivial but I've overlooked it. Currently I'm setting an intent for each of my views in the layout and this makes my code very messy. Here's what I'm doing currently:

```
remView = new RemoteViews(ctxContext.getPackageName(), R.layout.initial);
Intent ittRetry = new Intent(ctxContext, SettingsActivity.class);
ittRetry.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE);
ittRetry.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, intInstance);
PendingIntent pitRetry = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctxContext, 0, ittRetry, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);        
remView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_rows, pitRetry);
remView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_message, pitRetry);
wigManager.updateAppWidget(intInstance, remView);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Currently I'm setting an intent for each of my views in the layout and this makes my code very messy

However, that is your only option. You have to call `setOnClickPendingIntent()` for every widget for which you want to get control in a click.

You are welcome to use a loop, putting your widget IDs in an array and iterating over that array, calling `setOnClickPendingIntent()` in each pass.

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't verbose enough. I don't mean for each on my widget instances but for each of the views items in a widget's layout.

Comment: @MridangAgarwalla: No, you were perfectly clear, and my answer covers your scenario. You seem to be complaining about two lines of code in your app, where you call `setOnClickPendingIntent()`. Rather than having two dedicated `setOnClickPendingIntent()` calls, you can put your widget IDs (e.g., `R.id.widget_rows`) in an array and loop over them. IMHO, this would not be very useful except in very complex app widgets.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a transparent button on top of all your widget views at the end of your layout xml that covers the whole widget (**match_parent** is important!):

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/button"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
```

And reference it in your widget code:

```
[...]
views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button, pendingIntent);
[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution for this issue (years after the original question) is to set an id for the master layout. So my layout has a RelativeLayout and this has an id, which I can use for the pending intent.